# UIView beginanimation not working

Tags: uitableview, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am use this code when a cell is tapped in an uitableview that exists inside an uiview but is not doing the "flash" that is supposed to do on the cell when the user taps it.

```
-(IBAction)labelTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if(sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
        return;

    UIView *tappedview=[sender.view hitTest:[sender locationInView:sender.view] 
                                  withEvent:nil];

    UIView *contentview1=tappedview.superview.superview;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [contentview1 setAlpha:0];
    [contentview1 setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I tried also tappedview.superview but nothing happens.

Comment: What is the problem? Does the code run but not animate? Are you sure that `contentview1` is the correct view to animate?

Comment: Yes is the correct i fixed the code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this is working!

```
 UIView *contentview1=tappedview.superview;
[contentview1 setAlpha:0];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                     animations:^(void) 
    {
        // Animate the flash on tap


        [contentview1 setAlpha:1];

    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Done! Now show the pop up");
    )];
```

Comment: You know that you are doing UIView-animation inside a UIView-animation, right?

Comment: Yes i fixed the code. It is working now thanks. The issue was that uiview animation executed after the pop up show which is logical. It was my mistake.